# If the error terms in a regression setting are not observed, how can we ensure they're normally distributed?

Tags: regression, residuals, error, assumptions, gauss-markov-theorem

According to the G-M assumptions, we should assume spherical errors.

But my understanding is the errors -- as measured by the vertical distance from the true line of best fit to the response observations -- cannot be observed. Instead, our line of best fit is an estimate based on our $X = x$, our sample observations, and we call the difference between the line and the observed response variables the residuals.

So my question is: How do we check the Gauss-Markov assumptions if we cannot even validate the distribution of the errors?

Comment: While you cannot observe the errors, you can compute model *residuals*, which in some sense are estimators of the errors. This is not perfect (as estimators, they are not consistent, for example). But what else can you do?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen i guess i thought you could use a holdout to approximate somehow..